# Finding a username in a database using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm struggling with AJAX. I'm trying to make a form which let's the user fill in a username and then have AJAX check the database if it's still available. However, my form won't submit, but my check.php does work as I made the variable an string which is in the database and it echo's 1.

My form

```
<form onsubmit="geklikt(naam)">
<input type="text" id="naam" name="naam" placeholder="Vul je naam in">
<p id="message"></p>
<input type="submit" value="verzenden">
```

The javascript function with AJAX

```
    function geklikt(naam) {
        var naam = $("#naam").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"check.php",
            data:"naam =" + naam,
            success:function(data){
                if(data==0){
                    $("#message").html("<span style='font-size:13px; color: black'> Username available</span>");
                }
                else{
                    $("#message").html("<span style=font-size:13px; color: red'> Username already taken</span>");
                }
            }
        });

    };
```

the check.php code

```
// $username = $_POST["naam"];
$username = 'name1';
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM gegevens WHERE naam =   '$username' ");

$find = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo $find;

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @hood90, the <form> tag isn't propoerly closed - omission in the copy-paste, or plainly forgotten ?
Most browsers have developer's extensions - does "geklikt()" fire ? Does your dev extension gives an error ? 
If you hardcode a call to geklikt() ( e.g. <BODY onLoad="geklikt('azerty');"> ) , does the function then fire ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That the function to check the username doesn't work, or that the form won't submit afterwards?

Comment: what you have passed inside function ? geklikt(naam)? what is `naam` here ?

Comment: The function is not able to get fired whatever I seem to do. The PHP code works in check.php but for some reason the function just won't get called

Comment: @BAerts The form is properly closed I didn't copy it correctly sorry. I've tried it but it just does not do anything, literally nothing not even an error.

Comment: @Swati naam is the input which the user gives in the form

Comment: You haven't specified an "action" parameter for your form, what are you expecting it to do on submit?

Comment: @droopsnoot I did it but then it just redirect me to check.php and show me either a 1 or 0 which is not what i want. I want the results on home.html

Comment: You don't want to submit it to "check.php", because that just checks for the username being available. Once you know whether it's available, the "submit" is then what you do with the form data. Are you creating a new user, or something else?

Comment: @droopsnoot I don't want to create a new user, I just want to check if the name is taken or not.

Comment: @droopsnoot then use `keyup` event of jquery to achieve above or `click` event if you need to show result onclick of some button.

Comment: @hood90, did you try the other suggestions I made ? Or first program a small test button  <BUTTON onClick="geklikt('azerty');"> Try me !</BUTTON> and see if the function fires upon clicking the test button. You'll definitely have to check your browser's dev tools to see if it spots an error in the function. (oh, and try removing the semicolon after the last closing bracket of your function declaration ?)

Comment: @BAerts Well i've tried it and it did work, however i tried using a name that was in the database and it still said username available. What should I do now?

Comment: @Hood90, so what is currently the main problem: that the form submit doesn't work, or that the username validation doesn't function ? I'd focus on the onSubmit() function first. Try to re-implement, keep an alert() function at the start of 'geklikt()' to see if the function gets called upon form submit . If so, check if naam is filled in correctly. Again, I suggested to use the dev tools from your browser, but so far haven't seen any indication you're using them; what does your JS debugger say about content of variables ?

Comment: Also: you're using "naam" twice in the JS function: 1st time as formal argument, 2nd time in a var declaration. Will probably give problems

Comment: @BAerts The current problem is that the checking does not properly work. Also, When i try and submit the form, the message 'username is not available' shows up for 1 millisecond and the disappears.

About the 'naam' in the function, could you provide me with a solution for that? Should I name it differently?

Comment: If your code "var naam = $("#naam").val();" fetches the content directly from the DOM, I don't see why you'd need to pass it as a formal arg: so the function can just become "function geklikt()".

Comment: Confirm that the $_POST["naam"] is commented out in your version of check.php ? Because whatever you send, it will now always look for "name1" because of the "$username = 'name1';". Make sure the check.php halts at a breakpoint in a PHP debugger to check the value about to be sent back. Then check if that value makes it in your AJAX response.